# Customize look and feel of Android VideoView Interface

Tags: android, video, view, progress-bar, android-videoview

How can I customize the look and feel of VideoView interface in Android? I'd especially like to replace the progress bar, yellow background and media(pause/play) buttons with my own.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<VideoView
  android:id="@+id/surface_view"
  android:layout_width="320px"
  android:layout_height="240px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code**

```
public class VideoViewExample extends Activity {
   private VideoView mVideoView;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
     mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.sm));
     mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
     mVideoView.requestFocus();
     mVideoView.start();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd especially like to replace the progress bar, yellow background and media(pause/play) buttons with my own.

That is not "the `VideoView` user interface". That is the `MediaController`. It may be possible to style the `MediaController`, though I just elected to replace it [the last time I encountered this issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry).